# image not displaying in rails app

Tags: html, css, ruby, image

I'm having a very confusing problem with my rails app.  I am trying to display an image on a page, and I know the path is correct.  This is verified by "test.html", the entirety of which is:

```
<img src="/Users/xxxxx/MHE_website/app/assets/images/aggi5.jpg" >
```

And when I load this page locally I see the picture.  However, the exact same text does not load when I put it into my rails app.  What gives?  I notice that when I am hosting locally for developing, I get the following error message in my terminal:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/Users/xxxxx/MHE_website/app/assets/images/aggi5.jpg"):
```

What does this mean?  I've never had to do this before.  The following is my Gemfile, this may or may not be relevant but I'm at a loss.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

#toggle this on for dev mode
# group :development, :test do 
#   gem 'sqlite3'
# end

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

gem 'owlcarousel-rails', '~> 1.1.3.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development


group :development, :test do 
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production, :staging do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `image_tag` helper to display images in your application. See [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag).

You should use something like this in your view:

```
<%= image_tag( 'aggi5.jpg' ) %>
```

Comment: Excellent, that did it.  I wouldn't have thought to do that....any idea why I couldn't use a straight HTML tag?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the permission of the image to `777`. It should work